# Firefox losing functions after opening a link from Dash

Tags: 12.04, unity, firefox, unity-dash, lenses

I'm using Firefox as default browser in 12.04.1 LTS. Whenever I'm using the bookmarks-lens or the web-hitory-lens of the Unity Dash to open a bookmark in Firefox, pulldown-menus on websites don't get opened and the autofill finctionality is lost. Closing and re-launching Firefox makes everything work fine again.
Has anybody encountered this issue and knows a solution?

Thanks in advance!
Sascha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this may be the same bug you are experiencing https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/firefox/+bug/1027501

If you want to check there it appears it's been confirmed. Although I do not see a current fix or workaround.

Comment: Thanks, now I can be sure it's not due to a misconfiguration on my system.